# Problem with my account

Tags: discussion

I have the following problem with my account. I posted some questions with an unregistered account with the name Noob (e.g.[Nomenclature too long?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270026/nomenclature-too-long)). I provided my E-Mail Adress which I also use for this account.

Now the problem is that I cannot log-in with the Noob account (because I never registered it). But I want to write an important comment to my previous question (the question is very important for me). With the account MicFem (it is the account which I am using for writing this question) however I cannot comment on my previous question. This is why I posted my comment as an answer, but it was deleted.

What can I do to comment on that question?

Comment: There is a global policy that only SO mods can merge your accounts. See the help pages.

Comment: You may want to read this help page about merging accounts: http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts